# Troca de caracteres de uma mensagem em python

Tags: python, lista, criptografia, replace

Estou querendo fazer um programa que encripte de decripte uma mensagem pelo método zenit polar, que consiste em trocar essas letras entre si, alterando o texto sem o uso de acentos. 
Já consigo trocar as letras do primeiro grupo (zenit) pelas do segundo grupo (polar), e embaralhar um pouco o texto, mas não o contrário porque se eu só reverter o que eu já escrevi a mesma mensagem do input será retornada. Imagino que dê para usar as listas ou dicionários de uma forma melhor, mas não sei como.

Um resumo do que já tenho até o momento:

```
texto = input("Digite um texto: ")
lista_z = ['z', 'e', 'n', 'i', 't']

for z in lista_z:
    texto = texto.replace('z', 'p')

for e in lista_z:
    texto = texto.replace('e', 'o')

for n in lista_z:
    texto = texto.replace('n', 'l')

for i in lista_z:
    texto = texto.replace('i', 'a')

for t in lista_z:
    texto = texto.replace('t', 'r')

print(texto)
```

Estou começando agora e queria muito essa ajudinha pra achar uma solução, desde já muito obrigado.

Comment: A ideia do seu `for` está errada. você pode substituir todos esses `for` sem sentido por função da classe string, sugiro da uma estudada

Comment: Amigo, pode dar um exemplo pra eu entender melhor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu `for` esta percorrendo a `lista_z` porém não faz nada pq voce nao usa a variável dele para nada.

pra você entender como funciona o `for`

```
lista_z=['z','p','x','c','v']

for z in lista_z:
     print(z)
```

dessa forma vai imprimir cada item da lista, bem diferente do que você estava fazendo.

outra coisa é  olhar  as funções que a classe string tem. esse [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp) pode te ajudar a entender o que é uma string.

isso é para entender primeiro como percorrer uma lista item a item.

no seu código pode ser aplicado da seguinte forma, utilizei dicionário, porém tem a mesma ideia no `for` para percorrer  a lista

```
texto = input("Digite um texto: ") 
dic_z = {'z':'p', 'e':'o', 'n':'l', 'i':'a', 't':'r'}

for z in dic_z: 
     texto = texto.replace(z, dic[z])
```

Comment: @Lucas, coloquei ate a parte pra substituir os caracteres,  acredito que agora você vai entender o como funciona o `for` e poder aplicar na reordenação da frase. Qualquer dúvida tu fala

Comment: Acho que consegui entender seu exemplo e como usar o `for`, mas ainda não consigo aplicar totalmente. Quando escrevo algo com as letras do primeiro grupo, o _zenit_, tudo funciona, mas se eu criar um dicionário com o inverso do `dic_z`  para que o grupo  _polar_  também seja traduzido, aí recebo o meu "input" como resposta. Você teria alguma dica para impedir que o que já foi traduzido não passe pelo `for` novamente ou outra resolução parecida?

Comment: cara eu aconselho a utlizar funções. uma para o zenit e outra para polar. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) para entender como utilizar função.

Comment: acredito que tu ta iniciando em programação. desculpa se eu tiver errado,  um conselho que eu do é pra quem ta iniciando é focar em estrutura de dados

Comment: Sim, vou aprofundar mais nessas estruturas e continuar com o código depois. Obrigado pelo direcionamento!

Comment: continue com o código, é um bom exercício. estuda `if` por exemplo, vai te ajudar agora pra não passar pelo `for`. a medida tu for entendendo tu vai aplicando nele